# "Route "ctf.content" does not exist" when installing custom module

Tags: routes

I tried writing my own copy of the skeleton module from https://github.com/sidharrell/D8HWexample.git modules/custom/hello_world, but I thought I'd start by changing the module name and using "ctf" instead of "hello" in the routes. I tried to install the module but I got an exception.

> Route "ctf.content" does not exist

I deleted my module folder from beneath the custom folder and reloaded the page, but I still get this error. The site is now unusable.

Do I need to reinstall or is there an easy way to flush the cache or uninstall the module? I don't have drush installed (yet).

Comment: Use Drupal's CLI tool Drush: `drush cache:rebuild`

Answer (score 0):

You do need to clear the caches any time you edit routes. The simplest way is from the performance settings page: `/admin/config/development/performance`.

To change the module's name you'll need to replace every instance of the original name throughout every file in the module.

Comment: Something was cached and the whole site was broken, so I couldn't use the admin site. I had to re-install Drupal to fix it.